# Are assertions skipped when running in no debug mode?

Tags: c, assertion

I was wondering what actually happens with assertions when I have built my program and declared #define NDEBUG before the header.

Does it skip the line of code at execution time? or do something with that assert?

**Example:**

```
#define NDEBUG
#include<assert.h>

int main() {

    int i = 5;

    assert(i == 6);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to look the assertions while debugging if the programmer do something wrong, but when I run my code as final build I just want to skip the lines with assertions. I mean to don't slow down the program.

**EDIT :**

Ok I realised how macros as function-like work. Cute

Comment: Did you try to look into `assert.h`?

Comment: No, not at all :(

Comment: Then you might want to.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Looking into one implementation’s header can tell you only what that implementation does, not what the C standard requires.

Comment: Note that users are apt to stress your program harder than you do, so keeping the assertions will head off trouble at the pass.  At least, think about what should happen in the release build if the assertion would be triggered at runtime.  You might want to have a non-assertion check of the same condition that does appropriate error handling for non-debug (production) builds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the 2018 C standard, 7.2 1:

> The header `<assert.h>` defines the `assert` and `static_assert` macros and refers to another macro, `NDEBUG` which is not defined by `<assert.h>`. If `NDEBUG` is defined as a macro name at the point in the source file where `<assert.h>` is included, the assert macro is defined simply as:
>
> `#define assert(ignore) ((void)0)`
>
> The `assert` macro is redefined according to the current state of `NDEBUG` each time that `<assert.h>` is included.

In summary, if `NDEBUG` is defined, the `assert` maro will have no run-time effect. (During compilation, it does have a place in the syntax; you should follow it with a semicolon to form a complete expression statement, which is then essentially ignored.)

Comment: @EduardoG: If `NDEBUG` is defined when the header is included, a subsequent `assert(i == 6);` will be replaced by `((void)0);`.